# View logs for error running ember install command

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I am trying to run the following command (new project setup using some addon);

```
ember install <path to my-local-addon-0.0.0.tgz>
```

While I get the following error;

```
You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the install command.
```

I have ember-cli globally installed.

I wanted to know if I can get more details about the error after running commands like ember install..like a log or something which can convey more details for me to identify the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ember-cli project is set by `ember new project-name` or `ember addon addon-name`. Then you'd go inside project-name dir and for example try to `ember install something`. 
The error you get is self-descriptive: you are not in project directory.

And `ember install` doesn't have `--verbose` option.

Comment: Hmm...that is what it seems...thx...but any way of getting a more verbose or detailed error in general..

Answer (score -1):

try to add

–-verbose (or quick: -v) to your command!

```
ember install **-v** <path to my-local-addon-0.0.0.tgz>
```

Comment: It says The option '--verbose' is not registered with the install command. Run `ember in
stall --help` for a list of supported options.

Comment: Even ur updated command...ember install **-v** <path to my-local-addon-0.0.0.tgz> does not give any details except...You have to be inside an ember-cli...